# 403 forbidden nginx/1.8.3 - deploying ruby on rails application to aws-eb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed a rails application which was running on my local machine to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. After the deployment, I go the url, but I get the following message:

[image]

After researching on google, I found that I may need some script in my .ebextensions to grant permission. Thus, I added the following script in `.ebextensions/01_files.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       client_max_body_size 200M;

container_commands:
  # Remove the default nginx configuration generated by elastic beanstalk
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf"
```

But I still get the same message on opening the url. Can you help me what am I missing?

Also, I am not sure if keeping the file in `.ebextensions` folder runs the script or do I need to write another script to run the above script?

Comment: share your nginx configuration file

Comment: @Mayank - where can i find that file?

Comment: well you mush have created a conf file in `/etc/nginx/conf` folder, and for rails you have to setup `passenger` or `unicorn` also